# Blender 2.8 Texture

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to recreate a texture I created in V2.79. In that version I first created a colour using the material button, then I applied a cloud texture using the texture function. The result was an object that had a cloud effect on it.

The same features / buttons are present in V2.8 but they don't result in my object having a cloud texture. The cloud texture seem to be inactive. What is different / do I need to do something different to achieve the same effect?

Regards

Stephen

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post a picture!

Comment: Hello. Picture has been added.

Comment: I tought post a screenshot about the shader editor, or the material preset.

Comment: Sorry. The above screenshot shows how I would have added the cloud texture in version 2.79. My expectation is that the cube should have a cloud like surface. regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a brush preset what you adjusted. Try to use the node editor.
[image]

Comment: How do I make it red with white, instead of grey and white?

Comment: Found the answer. Connect 'colour' to 'subsurface'

Comment: Just discovered. Only need to connect 'fac' to 'subsurface'.